# Use a ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1-N32R8V as a Host USB to get data from a device using USB interface

Tags: c, usb, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf

I'm trying to use the usb interface from the esp32-s3 (USB Serial/Jtag controller) in order to get data in real time from a device that gives me the temperature via USB. The fact is that i don't know if is the correct way to do this, I am thinking of using the CDC-ACM from the ESP32-S3.